# I assume this is not normal but i have catalog_product_index_eav table and then catalog_product_index_eav_replica table

Tags: magento2, flat-catalog

I'm not sure why and if it's normal but i'm assuming it's not suppose to be there.

Lately, i've been having some problems with saving products and getting these errors on the admin upon save:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `entity_id` = ?, `created_in` = ?, `updated_in` = ?, `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id` = ?, `sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ?, `mst_search_weight` = ?, `mageworx_is_require` = ? WHERE (row_id = '4987')
```

I know you can probably fix it by updating the innodb_lock_wait_timeout to a higher value but that's just a bandaid and not addressing the actual problem.

Concurrently on the same product save sometimes i get this error: **"There is no active transaction"** and this one **Code does not exist**

I've tried killing any and all sleeping processes to free up the active ones but still to no avail nothing has fixed the issue. Occasionally it saves without a problem but it's like once in every 5 tries or more.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue in the past and honestly the fix was to increase `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`

The queries are too quick to catch, so we eventually enabled general logs:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

In our case we saw that the reindex was taking too long to complete because the customer has a LOT of products. While saving a product some admins would get that error, so after increasing the timeout we stopped seeing the issue.

I would say enable `general_log` and check the logs for when you get the error. See what other query is running at the same time, find the cause why that query is taking too long and fix that.
You can also just run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` on MySQL, but you might not catch the query. Enabling `general_log` will cause your DB to use more resources, so be careful with that.